# AudioServices: first sound plays, second does not .

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I think I know my problem is occurring but looking for validation and possibly a way to resolve.

I have a simple method `-(void)playMySound:(NSString *)sound` that I call in 2 places in the main ViewController:

1. In ViewDidLoad - When the initial view loads, the sound plays as expected
2. In an IBAction method that fires when a button is pressed. This sound does not play

I said I think I know why - the button is also hooked up to a Segue via Storyboard that loads a second view controller. I'm thinking that this in some way steps on the sound before its played (maybe deallocating the SystemSoundID?). I have confirmed that playMySound is firing from the button press.

I'm hoping this explanation is sufficient but if not I'll be happy to post my code.

Thanks
Tony.

Comment: Confused now. For 1., above I am playing "sound1.caf". For 2., above, I'm playing "sound2.caf". If I swap the sounds over, the first now does NOT play but the second one does. Both .caf files play in the file system and via the Xcode interface, but does not play on the device. I have made sure that "sound2.caf" is listed in "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases section too...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after all that I recreated my .caf from the original .mp3. Instead of opening the .mp3 in SoundStudio and exporting as a CAF, I followed the instructions from Apple by converting in the terminal using: /usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 {INPUT} {OUTPUT}. The resulting .caf works fine now.